# Is there a reason Kylo Ren never activated his lightsaber on-screen?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lightsaber, kylo-ren

On watching *The Force Awakens*, I noticed that Kylo Ren's lightsaber was always activated off-screen and then swung into view. In contrast, the other lightsaber used in the movie was activated on-screen in both instances.

Is there a reason for this choice, or is it coincidence?

Comment: Apropos nothing, when Lor San Tekka is sliced at, IIRC there's a lens flare :(

Comment: OK, I was wong in 1 detail but right in another. The trashing of the furniture scene - the whole saber is visible, hilt and all, start to finish.

Comment: i can guess that, out-of-universe it's harder to animate his lightsaber than the others so they tried to minimize those times?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - what's hard about creating a lens flare? :) I'm not sure but i think there's one EVERY time. Helps with animation, tremendously

Comment: It is seen activating onscreen in the forest fight between Kylo and Finn.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the scene where Kylo Ren receives the bad news about Poe and Finn escaping, we see him activate his saber

[image]

and of course, we've seen it in the [film's trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3FaOuYIYSc)

[image]

Comment: Ah it seems I was mistaken.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - I'll update with higher quality vids when Disney make some HD clips available.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: I find your lack of faith... understandable.

Answer (score 13):

I think you may be wrong - it DOES get activated on-screen when he is about to kill furniture on Star Destroyer. He holds it so we see the hilt on the right side of the screen, and the blade extends all the way across the screen.

Here's the WGA script for the scene:

> KYLO REN
>   The droid... stole a freighter?
>   LIEUTENANT MITAKA
>   Not exactly, sir. It had help.
>   Ren says nothing. Which says everything. Mitaka sweats.
>   LIEUTENANT MITAKA (CONT'D)
>   We have no confirmation, but we believe FN-2187 may have been helped
>   in the escape--
>   **Ren IGNITES HIS LIGHTSABER, TURNS AND SLASHES AT THE CONSOLE BEHIND HIM!**
>   HOLD ON Mitaka, who reacts, looks away -- winces.

[image]

Comment: When possible, I'll post the whole frame by frame, but for now I found you the final activation moment image.

Comment: I look forward to the frame by frame when it's available

Comment: It is indeed shown on-screen: http://i.giphy.com/3oxRmwelrMwZsu7bXy.gif

Comment: Isn't it also activated in one of the trailers or TV spots?

Comment: Maybe spoiler mark the script, in case anybody has opinions about what this scene says about Kylo's personality?

Comment: @CortAmmon - I don't think Kylo being an unstable Emo is much of an important spoiler, sorry. The site rules as I recall them are that spoilers are for major plot twists only.

Comment: @DVK Ahh.  I had defined it as "anything which might make me think twice about the movie" =)

Comment: @CortAmmon - that'd include 100% of it, no? :)